# how combine innerjoin query with 2 LCASE + REPLACE in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I try build searching with using `LCASE()` but it's not working?
this is part of source query, only this part have a problem error.

```
AND ((LCASE(SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","")) FROM product_description 
WHERE LCASE (REPLACE (pd.name," ",""))) LIKE '%liondlc10%'            
     OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('liondlc10')           
   )
   OR LCASE((SELECT REPLACE (p.model," ","")) FROM product WHERE LCASE  (REPLACE (p.model," ",""))) = 'liondlc10'
```

For full query :

```
SELECT p.product_id,
      (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total        
         FROM review r1        
        WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id        
          AND r1.status = '1'
        GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating
  FROM product p       
           LEFT JOIN  product_description pd 
                ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
           LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s 
                ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
 WHERE pd.language_id = '1'       
   AND p.status = '1'       
   AND p.date_available <= NOW()       
   AND p2s.store_id = '0'   


   AND ((LCASE(SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","")) FROM product_description 
WHERE LCASE (REPLACE (pd.name," ",""))) LIKE '%liondlc10%'            
     OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('liondlc10')         /* <-- part error */   
   )

   OR LCASE((SELECT REPLACE (p.model," ","")) FROM product 
   WHERE LCASE  (REPLACE (p.model," ",""))) = 'liondlc10'    /* <-- part error */


    OR LCASE(p.sku) = 'liondlc10'       
    OR LCASE(p.upc) = 'liondlc10'       
    OR LCASE(p.ean) = 'liondlc10'       
    OR LCASE(p.jan) = 'liondlc10'       
    OR LCASE(p.isbn) = 'liondlc10'       
    OR LCASE(p.mpn) = 'liondlc10'       
 GROUP BY p.product_id       
 ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

when I try this query, `mysql` said

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","")) FROM product_description
    WHERE LCASE (REP' at line 16

I could use `LCASE()`, but how would I do this with the following?
need help, already stack for 2 week :( .

Comment: Do not use function on columns in where clause /joins. It's very bad practice. Use function rather on values. Your approach kills database performance

Comment: @dcieslak but, if i not using where, how I can use replace ? can you give me example?

Comment: You have there from FROM product_description  where .  Is it OK?

Comment: @dcieslak well actually it's 2 query. when I try combine but fail, already using left in product_description pd. i thinking write full like that should be okay.

Comment: So why you cannot just : `AND  ( LCASE (REPLACE (pd.name,' ','')) LIKE '%liondlc10%   OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('liondlc10')   ) `

Comment: @dcieslak thank a lot, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dcieslak for your suggestion.

It's working now:

```
AND (LCASE(REPLACE(pd.name,' ','')) 
    LIKE '%liondlc10%' OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('liondlc10'))
    OR LCASE(REPLACE(p.model,' ','')) = 'liondlc10'
```